# Redux-persist for reactJS giving error : noop storage in Firefox 78.0.2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-persist

I have a crud app in ReactJS that uses redux-persist and is working without errors in Chrome.
The redux persist version is v6.

When I run the app in Firefox 78.0.2
the console returns following error:

```
> redux-persist failed to create sync storage. falling back to noop storage.
```

I have used localStorage in my my app.js but have removed and rebuild the app:
Without calling to localStorage in Firefox the app builds but does not persist.
In both cases no issue in Chrome..

I came along some answers for React-native but have not found the topic For ReactJS so far.

Anyone here encountered the same issue ?

here is my code:

Package.JSON:

```
      "devDependencies": {
   ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-uid": "^2.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ...
  ]
}
```

Index.HTML:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/lib/integration/react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { configureStore } from './store';
import App from './App.js';

const store = configureStore();
const persistor = persistStore(store);
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate
            loading={<div>Loading app..</div>}
            persistor={persistor}>
        <App />
        </PersistGate>
    </Provider>,
    document.querySelector('#root'),
);
```

Store.JS:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import autoMergeLevel2 from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel2';
import { articles } from './services/actionReducer';

const reducers = {
    articles,
};

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
    stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2,
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers(reducers);
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
export const configureStore = () => createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In redux-persist v6, you try changing as follows:

```
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

const persistConfig = {
//...
storage,
}
=>
const persistConfig = {
//...
storage: AsyncStorage,
}
```

Comment: I am not looking for a react native solution, the issue occurs in a react app. Unless this is also working for React app..